# Decrementar variável do PHP ao clicar num botão de form

Tags: php

Quero decrementar uma variável numérica quando carrego num botão de nome `btn`.

Este é o código que tentei:

```
$month = date("m");

$mes=1;
if(isset($_POST["btn"])) { 

    $month = $month-$mes;
    $mes++;

}
```

O problema é que obtenho sempre o mesmo valor.

Comment: Sim, você está dizendo que $mes é 1 e $month é o mes corrente, então vai subtrair 1 do mês atual sempre que clicar no botão. Você precisa guardar o valor novo em algum lugar da página, por exemplo no próprio botão ou em algum campo escondido e usá-lo no clique seguinte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está zerando os valores a toda chamada do PHP.

Eis um exemplo bem simplificado de como persistir dados entre um clique e outro:

```
<?php
   if( isset( $_POST['mes'] ) ) {
      $mes = 0 + $_POST['mes'];
   } else {
      $mes = 0 + date('m');
   }

   if( @$_POST['btn'] == '-' ) { 
      $mes--;
   } else if( @$_POST['btn'] == '+' ) {
      $mes++;
   }

   echo "Mes: $mes<br>";
   echo '<form method="post">';
   echo '<input type="submit" name="btn" value="-">';
   echo '<input type="submit" name="btn" value="+">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="mes" value="'.$mes.'">';
   echo '</form>';
?>
```

<sub>E antes que alguém reclame, supressão em PHP é pra isso mesmo. É pra usar onde não tem problema. ISSET num caso desses é que não faz sentido.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado, mas por exemplo caso esteja no mes=4, e carrego no + volta m ao 12, e não ao 5.

Comment: Tinha um errinho de sintaxe nos parênteses, mas é exatamente o mesmo código que está aqui, veja: http://ninja.net.br/akm.php

Comment: Certifique-se de copiar a versão mais atualizada, e testar. Depois você vai modificando aos poucos pra sua necessidade, assim quando mudar algo que atrapalhe o funcionamento, você vai perceber o que é que pode ter dado problema.

Comment: Sim funciona perfeitamente, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Este função pode ser feita em javascript também se necessário, e mandar apenas o mês que foi configurado. Vou dar um exemplo.

```js
$("#btnEnviar").on("click" , function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'caminhodoarquivo.php' ,
    type : 'POST' ,
    dataType : 'json' ,
    data : { 
      mes : $("#txtMes").val()
    },
    sucess : function(resultado){
      //Faz o retorno para a o usuário
    },
    error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
      console.error(textStatus);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="frmMes" class="form">
  <input type="number" id="txtMes" min="1" max="12" />
  <button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="btb btn-primary">
    <span>Enviar</span>
  </button>
 </form>
```

Observações:
Usando o elemento number (input do tipo number) e as propriedades min e max, você evita erros bobos como por exemplo mês 14 ou -1.

Espero ter ajudado,

Douglas Dreer